# LXDE ubuntu 17.04 - The use of dead keys to type accents does not seem to work

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, 17.04, ibus, language-support

The use of dead keys to type accents does not seem to work in any progam. I have physical keyboard MICROSOFT NATURAL (English) and languages installed Portuguese (Brasil) and English (USA). For example typing ' then c , or any accent with the layout 'international with dead keys' leads to a character without accent. Ibus is activated, and deactivating it does not solve the issue.

Comment: One idea: Can you create an additional user for test purposes, log in as that user, and check if the issue is present for that user too?

Comment: I have the same problem with Ubuntu MATE 17.04

Answer (score 1):

**Lucas Simon**'s solution worked perfectly in my *Lubuntu 18.04.1* .

As I don't normally login as root, I opened an LXTerminal and ran the **sudo** variant of **Lucas Simon**'s command line:

```
sudo apt install ibus && ibus-setup --xim
```

This quickly downloaded & installed some *ibus* packages, after which all my dead key accents immediately worked as intended - no further steps were needed, and I didn't even need to restart anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in Lubuntu 17.07. my keyboard is PT_BR ABNT2 layout

Run it:

```
apt install ibus && ibus-setup --xim
```

Choose restart keyboard layout. And try again yéééééééééééééah

Comment: 17.07? What's that? Have you included all the steps here? I've found it less than trivial to set up ibus layouts!